# iTop, where to implement onchange javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

the iTop fourms are pretty inactive and I am pretty stuck so I thought I'd ask here if that is ok. I am attempting to add my own piece of javascript to work onchange of the iTop organization select bar.

Here is a link to iTop if needed: http://www.combodo.com/spip.php?page=rubrique&id_rubrique=8

Extra info on my iTop forum question, no answers yet: https://sourceforge.net/p/itop/discussion/922360/thread/dd1da92f/

So iTop is a piece of software made using php, html, js and css but I am new to php so I have ran into a little bit of a problem. I am trying to implement a piece of javascript which will change the top-bar of the css to a different colour based on organization, I made a small prototype independent of iTop and it works perfectly. However I am unable to add the onchange() method along with the javascript as the main user interface is generated dynamically using php. I have tried numerous ways to implement the javascript but none have worked. Here are some pictures of iTop and code to help:

This is a picture showing the inspect element of iTop and how I came to believe jquery-1.7.1.min.js may be the correct location to place the code.

[image: Inspect element showing that jquery-1.7.1.min.js has a listener]

So I have tried going into this file and copy and pasting in my Java Script code but in some locations it has no affect and within function(a){....} it results in iTop only displaying a blank page, I could be going about this totally wrong but from what I have seen this file seems to be the one I am to edit to get what I want.

here is the javascript i am trying to implement:

```
var changeStyle = function(){

    //HTML
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("org_id").value;

    //CSS
    var trimColor = document.querySelector("#top-bar");

    //BT
    if(selectedValue=="3"){
        //change banner colour
        trimColor.style.backgroundColor= "#3498db";
    }

    //Bell Aliant
    else if(selectedValue=="27"){
        //change banner colour
        trimColor.style.backgroundColor= "#f1c40f";
    }

    //Bell Canada
     else if(selectedValue=="26"){
         trimColor.style.backgroundColor= "#e74c3c"; 
    }

    else
        trimColor.style.backgroundColor="#ecf0f1";
}
```

Here are some pictures of it working in my non iTop version of just HTML, JS and CSS:

[image: Red]

[image: yellow]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although I do not believe it is the best solution I have entered the following code into jquery-1.1.1.min.js as shown

[image]

And I have achieved the desired result, the trim now changes with the organization change, this however is not the perfect solution I was looking for and is a bit slow but not in the sense that you'd get annoyed, at least in my opinion. Mission Accomplished for the moment!

[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer is far from being the "right answer" as it modifies a source code file which will be overwritten during the next upgrade. iTop has proper API to do so, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I'll answer it anyway as the answer is still ok for the last versions of iTop.

To inject some JS in the page, you have to use the **iPageUIExtension::GetNorthPaneHtml(iTopWebPage $oPage)** API which gives you acces to the iTopWebPage object. Then you can use the various public methods such as "iTopWebPage::add_ready_script($sScript)" to inject $sScript into all of the backoffice pages. Moreover, the script will be executed once the DOM is ready.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/Molkobain/itop-console-tooltips/blob/30af0d59820ddc8568edbb059303f327a7e8007a/dist/molkobain-console-tooltips/molkobain-handy-framework/console/pageuiextension.class.inc.php).

```
class PageUIExtension implements iPageUIExtension
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function GetNorthPaneHtml(iTopWebPage $oPage)
    {
        ...

        $oPage->add_linked_script(utils::GetAbsoluteUrlModulesRoot() . 'molkobain-handy-framework/common/js/handy-framework.js');
    }
}
```

*Note: You will need to make your own iTop extension, check [here](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=2_7_0%3Acustomization%3Aadd-attribute-sample) for how to do it.*